# Line integral along the boundary of the intersection of a plane and a parabaloid

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

I was stuck on the following question on a practice exam.
For the vector field
$\vec F(x,y,z) = (\frac{-y}{x^2+2y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+2y^2}, 1) $

Evaluate $$\int_K\vec F \vec dr,$$

with K the simple closed curve given by $z = x^2+y^2$ and $x+y+z = 2$.

Since K is a simple closed curve i thought i had to use Stokes theorem and i computed $curl(\vec F) = 0$, but i didnt really know how to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Stokes' theorem cannot be applied naively to the disk because the vector field is defined on a subset of $\Bbb{R}^3$ that is not simply connected (the $z$ axis is taken out). What you can do is define a surface with two boundaries, one being the curve in the problem, other other being the ellipse $x^2+2y^2=1$ in the plane $z = 100$ which gives us

$$\int_CF\cdot dr - \int_{x^2+2y^2=1\cap z=100}F\cdot dr = \iint_S \operatorname{curl}F\cdot dS = 0$$

$$\implies \int_C F\cdot dr = \frac{1}{(1)}\int_{x^2+2y^2=1\cap z=100} -ydx+xdy+dz$$

$$ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin^2t+\cos^2t\:dt = \pi\sqrt{2}$$

from parametrizing appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you explain how you got to using that particular ellipse?

Comment: @Jedberry in order to use Stokes' theorem in a valid way the surface must not cross the $z$ axis at all, but that means it must have a second boundary that also goes around the $z$ axis once. With that in mind, why do you think this particular ellipse was chosen out of all curves that surround the $z$ axis ?